# Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized) In nextJs axios post()

Tags: next.js, next-auth

```
"use client";

import axios from "axios";
import { useRouter } from "next/navigation";
import { createContext, useState } from "react";

const AuthContext = createContext();
export const AuthProvider = ({ children }) => {
const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
const [error, setError] = useState(null);
const [loading, setLoading] = useState(null);
const [updated, setUpdated] = useState(false);

const router = useRouter();

const registerUser = async ({ name, email, password }) => {
try {
  const { data } = await axios.post(
    `${process.env.API_URL}/api/auth/register`,
    {
      name,
      email,
      password,
    }
  );

  if (data?.user) {
    router.push("/");
  }
} catch (error) {
  setError(error?.response?.data?.message);
}
};


const addNewAddress = async (address) => {
try {
  console.log("im in authcontext", address);
  const { data } = await axios.post(
    `${process.env.API_URL}/api/address`,
    address
  );

  // console.log("address in authcontext", address);
  if (data) {
    router.push("/me");
  }
} catch (error) {
  setError(error?.response?.data?.message);
}
};

const updateAddress = async (id, address) => {
try {
  const { data } = await axios.put(
    `${process.env.API_URL}/api/address/${id}`,
    address
  );

  if (data?.address) {
    setUpdated(true);
    router.replace(`/address/${id}`);
  }
} catch (error) {
  setError(error?.response?.data?.message);
}
};

const deleteAddress = async (id) => {
try {
  const { data } = await axios.delete(
    `${process.env.API_URL}/api/address/${id}`
  );

  if (data?.success) {
    router.push("/me");
  }
} catch (error) {
  setError(error?.response?.data?.message);
}
};

const clearErrors = () => {
setError(null);
};

return (
<AuthContext.Provider
  value={{
    user,
    error,
    loading,
    updated,
    setUpdated,
    setUser,
    registerUser,
    updateProfile,
    updatePassword,
    addNewAddress,
    updateAddress,
    deleteAddress,

    clearErrors,
  }}
>
  {children}
</AuthContext.Provider>
);
};

export default AuthContext;
```

Here the axios get method works but the post is throwing unauthorized error. Not able to find the solution to the issue. How do I resolve this issue. Also the session gets null after hitting the post but initially session has the data soon after hitting post session becomes null. Not only post but also put method in the axios.